# UE4 Missing Plugin "OculusAvatar"

Tags: unreal-engine4, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I'm trying to open a project for VR development, but when I try to open it, this popup appears

[image]

So I went to the Plugins to check if the plugin was disabled and the plugin doesn't even appear in my UE4.27.2

Answer (score 1):

"Avatars will no longer be included with Unreal Engine starting with version 4.26."

https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unreal/as-avatars-426-unreal/